# Can $_SERVER variables in PHP be changed by the user? If so how?

Tags: php

I need to use $_SERVER variables like SCRIPT_FILENAME for a mvc framework I'm writing. I'm wondering if a user can change things like that. Say the user requests index.php, can they fake the SCRIPT_FILENAME variable and rename it to something else that is being sent over?

Answer (score 4):

Some `$_SERVER` values are safe, others are not. The unsafe ones mostly start with `HTTP_` and are the HTTP headers sent by the user's browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

See [this post:  How to bypass the REFERER security check](http://www.mustap.com/phpzone_post_62_how-to-bypass-the-referer-se).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user doesn't have access to some way that re-directs the execution of the script through another script, or access to the server, I'd say no.
Also, if you're really worried about that, you can use `__FILE__` which doesn't depend on user data.